# Add tooltip to highcharts javascript

Tags: javascript, highcharts, tooltip

I'm running into some problems with adding some information to tooltip.

Basically, my highcharts gets generated dynamically, and everything is working great, but I would like an additional field to show up in tooltip, and I cannot make it work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the snippet of code I am using which is generating an "undefined" label:

```
tooltip: {
formatter: function () {
var s;
if (this.point.name) {
s = '' + this.point.name + ': ' + this.y + ' fruits';
} else {
s = '' + this.series.title + ': ' + this.y + ' ' + this.x;
}
return s;
}
},
```

And here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9zN2M/2/

Answer (score 3):

It looks like `this.series` does not have a `title` property.

It does have a `name` property, though, so you should be able to use `this.series.name`.